# What does the phrase tzatzuchey chalav mean here?

Tags: halacha, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

The [Beth Yosef YD 115:3:10](https://tur.alhatorah.org/Dual/Beit_Yosef/Yoreh_Deah/115.3#m7e0n6) uses the phrase "**צחצוחי חלב**". What does this phrase mean in this context?

The subject here is about non Jewish milk, cheese, and butter and the heter of buying non Jewish butter.

Comment: tzatzuchey chalav = droplets of milk. Have a look on Aruch HaShulchan YD 115:20-24, it will probably make it clear for you. https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.115.20?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: @JulioGB thank you. will look there as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original context is [Abhodah Zara 35a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.35a.11?lang=bi) and refers to particles of [non-kosher] milk. The [Jastrow entry on צִחְצוּחַ](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A6%D6%B4%D7%97%D6%B0%D7%A6%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%97%D6%B7.1?lang=bi)  defines it as:

> particles of diluted milk (in the holes of cheese)